# Unable to add margins in iTextSharp document having images

Tags: pdf, itext

**Requirement:**
A large image (dynamic) needs to be split and shown in PDF pages. If image can't be accomodated in one page then we need to add another page and try to fit the remaining portion and so on.

So far I am able to split the image in multiple pages, however it appears that they are completely ignoring the margin values and so images are shown without any margins.

Please see below code:

```
string fileStringReplace = imageByteArray.Replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "");
        Byte[] imageByte = Convert.FromBase64String(fileStringReplace);
        iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageByte);
        float w = image.ScaledWidth;
        float h = image.ScaledHeight;
        float cropHeight = 1500f;

        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle page = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(1150f, cropHeight);
        var x = page.Height;
        Byte[] created;

        iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(page, 20f, 20f, 20f, 40f); --This has no impact

        using (var outputMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, outputMemoryStream);
            writer.CloseStream = false;

            document.Open();
            PdfContentByte canvas = writer.DirectContentUnder;

            float usedHeights = h;

            while (usedHeights >= 0)
            {
                usedHeights -= cropHeight;
                document.SetPageSize(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(1150f, cropHeight));
                canvas.AddImage(image, w, 0, 0, h, 0, -usedHeights);

                document.NewPage();
            }

            document.Close();

            created = outputMemoryStream.ToArray();

            outputMemoryStream.Write(created, 0, created.Length);
            outputMemoryStream.Position = 0;
        }
        return created;
```

I also tried to set margin in the loop by document.SetMargins() - but that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing different things.

When you create margins, be it while constructing the `Document` instance or by using the `setMargins()` method, you create margins for when you let iText(Sharp) decide on the layout. That is: the margins will be respected when you do something like `document.Add(image)`.

However, you do not allow iText to create the layout. You create a `PdfContentByte` named `canvas` and you decide to add the image to that canvas using a transformation matrix. This means that you will calculate the `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, and `f` value needed for the `AddImage()` method.

You are supposed to do that Math. If you want to see a margin, then the values `w`, `0`, `0`, `h`, `0`, and `-usedHeights` are wrong, and you shouldn't blame iTextSharp, you should blame your lack of insight in analytical geometrics (that's the stuff you learn in high school at the age of 16).

This might be easier for you:

```
iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageByte);
float w = image.ScaledWidth;
float h = image.ScaledHeight;
// For the sake of simplicity, I don't crop the image, I just add 20 user units
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle page = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(w + 20, h + 20);
iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(page);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, outputMemoryStream);
// Please drop the line that prevents closing the output stream!
// Why are so many people making this mistake?
// Who told you you shouldn't close the output stream???
document.Open();
// We define an absolute position for the image
// it will leave a margin of 10 to the left and to the bottom
// as we created a page that is 20 user units to wide and to high,
// we will also have a margin of 10 to the right and to the top
img.SetAbsolutePosition(10, 10);
document.Add(Image);
document.Close();
```

Note that `SetAbsolutePosition()` also lets you take control, regardless of the margins, as an alternative, you could use:

```
iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageByte);
float w = image.ScaledWidth;
float h = image.ScaledHeight;
// For the sake of simplicity, I don't crop the image, I just add 20 user units
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle page = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(w + 20, h + 20);
iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(page, 10, 10, 10, 10);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, outputMemoryStream);
// Please drop the line that prevents closing the output stream!
// Why are so many people making this mistake?
// Who told you you shouldn't close the output stream???
document.Open();
// We add the image to the document, and we let iTextSharp decide where to put it
// As there is just sufficient space to fit the image inside the page, it should fit,
// But be aware of the existence of a leading; that could create side-effects
// such as forwarding the image to the next page because it doesn't fit vertically
document.Add(Image);
document.Close();
```

Comment: Let's take a look at the first solution:  There is a line "iTextSharp.text.Rectangle page = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(w + 20, h + 20);" - However, my image will be (mostly) in big size. If we add 20,20 then it won't fit in one page. What will happen to the portion of image which is outside the page?

Comment: Also, will be possible for you to guide me on where to find documentation for PDFContentByte.AddImage method

Comment: Solution 1 doesn't work. As I mentioned in my question. I just don't want to add image, it will be always big and so I have to do some work to fit it. Which I am doing, but as margin is getting ignored. I need to find out real and smart solution.

Comment: The image measures `w` by `h`. If you create a rectangle that measures `w + 20` by `h + 20`, the image will always fit that rectangle. The Math needed for the `AddImage()` method is explained in different books I wrote about iText. Some of those are available for free. You claim that Solution 1 doesn't work, but you probably didn't try it, because **there will be a margin** if you use `SetAbsolutePosition(10, 10)`. I am the original developer of iText, and I think you are a troll trying to provoke me by saying *it doesn't work.* Please go away if you're not seriously looking for an answer.

Comment: I did tried, but it fits entire image in one page. Further, I am referring your own solution provided at http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-show-image-large-dimensions-across-multiple-pages  - the only diff is that I need margins. It's confusing now.

Comment: You can use any example *on condition that you understand the example.* It seems that you don't understand. You *explicitly* use a parameter that reduces the margin to 0 in your code. Also: if you want a top and a bottom margin, you will need to *clip* the image. Why don't you hire someone who knows how to use iText to achieve what you want?

Comment: If you don't mind, I would like to learn iTextSharp. further, this is first time I am using iTextSharp. ( Note that I have used many other opensource projects) but they weren't this difficult to handle.

Comment: Which books about iText did you read? Have you taken a look at ISO-32000-1?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121777/discussion-between-techturtle-and-bruno-lowagie).